# Login Failed with remote desktop

Tags: rdp, login

I am trying to RDP to one of our servers over a Citrix VPN. However, after accessing the machine, I an greeted with the following message:

> Login failure: user account restriction. Possible reasons are blank passwords not allowed, logon hour restrictions, or a policy restriction has been enforced.

I am entering a username and password in order to get to the server, and I am also able to browse the server in Windows Explorer and view the event log remotely using these credentials.

I see the following `Audit Failure` event in the server's security event log:

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        <Sid>
    Account Name:       <ServerName>$
    Account Domain:     <Domain>
    Logon ID:       0x<LogonId>

Logon Type:         10

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        S-1-0-0
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xc000006e
    Sub Status:     0x0

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x744
    Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   -
    Source Network Address: <ip>
    Source Port:        <port>

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      User32 
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

~snip~
```

So it looks to me like my credentials aren't being passed to the winlogon process.

My colleagues are all able to remote to this server, and the only difference, as far as I can tell, is that I am remoting from a Windows 10 machine, whereas they are on Windows 7. I believe the server is 2008 R2. This is using a "support" account, so we are using the same credentials.

Why are my credentials not being used, and what can I do to be able to log on?

Comment: Have you compared your account `RSOP` with an account that is able to login?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what RSOP is. But we are all logging in using the same shared "support" credentials, so could it be to do with them?
(Sorry, I realise this was important info, so I'll add it to the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke to a colleague, and she had had a similar issue with RDPing from Windows 10. She told me to change some local group policy settings related to credential delegation, and everything now works!

I don't have time to investigate which setting made the difference (I had to restart for the changes to take effect), but here are some before and after screenshots:

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Comment: Thanks for editing in the images!